# Saving Model Sort Order With Django and jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, sorting

I am trying to implement [sorting of Django model instances using jQuery UI Sortable](http://rstrobl.com/blog/2012/01/19/sorting-django-model-instances-jqueryui-sortable/). The client-side sorting action works when I drag and drop images but the sort order is not saved to the database. After dragging-and-dropping images I get the following logged to the console: `"POST /versions/1/sort/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0`, so the request seems fine. **UPDATE:** Here's an example of the request logged to the console using [this debugging technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137069/412329):

```
"POST /versions/1/sort/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
format=2013-10-23 11:22:39,604 - django.db.backends - DEBUG - (0.000) SELECT "versions_image"."id", "versions_image"."version_id", "versions_image"."image_text", "versions_image"."status", "versions_image"."order" FROM "versions_image" WHERE "versions_image"."id" = 3 ; args=(3,)
format=2013-10-23 11:22:39,609 - django.db.backends - DEBUG - (0.000) SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "versions_image" WHERE "versions_image"."id" = 3  LIMIT 1; args=(3,)
format=2013-10-23 11:22:39,613 - django.db.backends - DEBUG - (0.000) UPDATE "versions_image" SET "version_id" = 1, "image_text" = Zing, "status" = 1, "order" = 0 WHERE "versions_image"."id" = 3 ; args=(1, u'Zing', 1, 0, 3)
format=2013-10-23 11:22:39,621 - django.db.backends - DEBUG - (0.000) SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."session_key" = kuh0mwboss6q7vmov6ydzs0o1gccsspi  AND "django_session"."expire_date" > 2013-10-23 09:22:39.619910 ); args=('kuh0mwboss6q7vmov6ydzs0o1gccsspi', u'2013-10-23 09:22:39.619910')
```

Why is the Image order value not being saved?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Version(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Image(models.Model):
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)
    image_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.image_text
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from versions import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<version_id>\d+)/sort/$', views.sort, name='sort'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from versions.models import Image, Version
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def sort(request, version_id):
    for index, image_pk in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('image[]')):
        image = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=int(str(image_pk)))
        image.order = index
        image.save()
        return HttpResponse('')
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_head %}
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  // Sortable photos
  // jQuery and jQuery-UI are in base.html
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var serial = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'versions:sort' version.id %}",
      type: "post",
      data: serial
    });
      },
    }).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
{% endblock extra_head %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ version.title }}</h1>
    <ul id="sortable">
    {% for image in version.image_set.all %}
      <li id="image_{{ image.pk }}" class="ui-state-default">
        {{ image.image_text }}
        <span class="move">&#x1F503;</span>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What does `request.POST.getlist('image[]')` look like? Also, I think it should be `image` not `image[]`.

Comment: I updated the question with the logged debugging info. For some reason the order in UPDATE is always 0. I tried `image` instead of `image[]` but still no success.

Comment: Well. There's only one image, so it's the first one. So it's order is "0".

Comment: In my test data there are five images. I think the problem is something else. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for laying out such a great example of using jQuery Sortable with Django. Every other google result refers to using it in the Django Admin UI, which is not how I needed to use it. Your code, with a few tweaks to match my system, worked perfectly!

Comment: That's very kind of you, thank you. I'm sure I found this somewhere else, but don't remember at this point (probably in the now-broken link in the original question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move line "return HttpResponse('')" out of for cycle in your sort view.
Thanks for implementation example.

Comment: Thank you very much for this — I completely overlooked that! Will try this solution on my code and accept this as soon as I confirm it works.

Comment: To make it work I also had to: 1) Add `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt` to views.py and decorate the sort view with `@csrf_exempt` (in order to avoid 405 not allowed error). 2) Change the .ajax url in detail.html to `url: "{% url 'detail' version.id %}sort/",`. It is working now, thanks again — answer accepted.