# Show Django errors on console rather than Web Browser

Tags: python, django, rest, extjs

I'm developing a REST application using ExtJS4 and using Django 1.6.5 to create a simple mock API for this application, that for now I want to only save some data in the SQLite db and output some other to the console.

While testing the `GET` methods is fairly simple, when I have a problem with `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` I can't see the returning error from Django in the browser. Is there any way to make these errors show up in the Django's developer server console instead?

Comment: If you are using the Django runserver command then you should be seeing the errors in the same console.

Comment: Not the complete error log, like Django shows in the browser. In the console, Django only shows a 500 error like this `[12/Jun/2014 13:13:16] "POST /servers/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11394`

Comment: I think you have to use `print`.

Comment: While your idea is not really the answer to the question, it is a good direction, I surrounded the whole method with `try/except` to try to find the error.

Comment: The answers here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137042/how-can-i-get-django-to-print-the-debug-information-to-the-console

Answer (score 1):

I know that's not the answer to the question, but it is the solution to the proposed problem. In Google Chrome, if you open the Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), you can go to the `Network` tab, click on the request with error (it will be red), and then click on the `Response` tab, in the panel that opened by the right. There, you will be able to see the errors for `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, Bruno. It doesn't answer the question, like you said, but it answers the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your **views.py** you just have to print *Response.data* with serializer's errors and Python web server will show the details of failure. Like in this example:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = DataSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        error = Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        print(error.data)
    return error
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py, set DEBUG=True to make Django show the whole error information in the web response.

With DEBUG=False you have to manually print the error to console using print or export it to a log with some log tool.

Comment: `DEBUG` is set to `True`. The problem is not that I'm not able to see the error in the web response, I am, if I use tools like [REST test](http://resttesttest.com/). But as I said, I'm trying to test methods from `HTTP` `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` from a REST application which doesn't show the web response after making the requests to the Django application. So showing these errors in the console would save me a LOT of time and work.