# Django console not displaying prints on console

Tags: django, printing, console

I am having issues displaying my `print` statements on the console following a `./manage.py runserver` command. Is there any way that I can un-surpress this information? I have tried changing the `verbosity` level, but there seems to be no change.

Comment: If you are using development server, it usually prints to console. You can also try logging http://stackoverflow.com/a/5137069/2698552

Comment: ChillarAnand is right. So you're asking for a solution to a problem that people normally do not have because Django behaves the way you wish it to behave **by default**. There is something you are doing which interferes, or there is something in your own specific setup that interferes.