# How to debug internal server errors in eclipse when coding a django project?

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, django-1.7

I have a lot of trouble in debugging an ajax view. That's a view which expects a post request and then returns a json object. It causes an internal error 500, but eclipse doesn't give more information. The standard debug page cannot be accessed, because the view redirects if there is no post data.

What is the best approach to tackle these problems? Can I get eclipse/pydev      to just tell me what the internal error 500 exactly is? Or do I really have to get a browser plugin and construct POST Data? (Which might be difficult, because a file upload is involved.)

Effectively I'm looking for a way to get the exception message in the console. Currently it just says:

```
[16/Feb/2015 17:38:03] "POST /fotos/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10907
```

Which is not a big help.

**Important:** This question is about how to make debugging easier and not about fixing this particular view. So no need to ask for code or logfiles of that view. It's a general question about how to go ahead.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Internal server errors can be generated in many ways. One of the most prominent ways is having a syntax error in the server code. The syntax error can range from typos to incorrect indentation(in python). Try debugging your python code. Try to find the point of error and see if there is a misspell or indentation error like using tabs instead of spaces(or vice-versa).

Also, if you're running Django in debug mode, open the link giving the error in a browser, and it will directly show you if there are any compile time errors in the code.

EDIT: And I totally missed the part where you mentioned that "the standard debug page cannot be accessed". Well in that case I'd resort to using standard print statements for debugging and check server logs for the point of failure.

Comment: That's the way I'm working right now, but it seems ineffective. Isn't there a way to make the testserver more verbose in the shell so it can just tell me in what line the error occured.

Comment: I'm guessing this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137042/how-can-i-get-django-to-print-the-debug-information-to-the-console

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint (click on the left of the line or just tight click add Breakpoint to the spot). Once the source code gets to the point a debugging menu is opened containing:

1. -Variables and their values
2. -All your breakpoints