# What Django does when there is no terminal to print to?

Tags: python, django, terminal

Sometimes I forget to remove print statements that I add to debug my Django codes. So they go to production code and are supposed to print something in the terminal, but there is no terminal in production to print at.
I'm wondering what happens in such scenarios? Does it have any impact on the code's performance?

Edit: My question is about the nature of stdout in Django production. So nothing to do with debugging per se.

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` will be connected to *something* when you run Django, even in a WSGI container, even if it is `/dev/null` or a file. That's where it'll go to. Read the documentation of your WSGI server.

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar That question has nothing to do with mine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is that `something` stdout in Django production?

Comment: @Babr: 'Django production' is way too vague a description. There is no one way to put Django into production.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right. I mean Gunicorn in particular.

Comment: @Babr: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#capture-output

Comment: so what happens to the pront statement when there is no `--capture-output` (like in my case)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No they don't. Only on startup. But it's perfectly valid to close them, like "[well-behaved daemons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)" do.

Comment: @Melvyn: ick, misread the source. Indeed, I meant at startup, but [gunicorn redirects output to /dev/null](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/fbd151e9841e2c87a18512d71475bcff863a5171/gunicorn/util.py#L450-L484). So the answer for Gunicorn is: output goes to /dev/null (discarded) unless you set `--capture-output`, at which point stdout and stderr are sent to the gunicorn log.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're linking the wrong line. That's about stdin. stdout/stderr are a little more complex as per comments below that. In fact, the way it's implemented, you can't really tell where it goes from looking at the config. I guess `--capture-output` is linked to that `enabled_stdio_inheritance` kwarg, but then there's mention of `--error-log` assumption. I trust your experience though, but where it ends up with what set of flags isn't that simple and actually makes it a good question :)

Comment: @Melvyn: I definitely linked to the stdout/stderr section (where they are redirected to /dev/null if connected to a terminal). `--capture-output` re-dupes the output to a log, see https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/2b839ca14437c61780d6eaaa8b24ad31e021f2c6/gunicorn/glogging.py#L201-L207

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Django to print the debug information to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137042/how-can-i-get-django-to-print-the-debug-information-to-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by production code,you mean you have deployed it on a server.It will the same way as it works on your localhost.

For example,if you deploy it on Heroku and check the Logs of your application,you would see that line printed,that's all.On many servers,there is a command line feature available.

There will be no effect on the performance untill and unless you have a really complex and dense deployment.

**Edit**:please read:[link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn)

Comment: Don't know how is deployment on Heroku. I mean deployments using Gunicorn.

Comment: Heroku is a cloud platform that lets companies build, deliver, monitor and scale apps,for python applications,you need gunicorn as a pre-requisite.please see the updated answer.